# How can I display Assamese text in Android app?

Tags: android

I am very new to android app development. And my first app is a text based biographical app that contains Assamese text (Indic language). I already have all the text written in Unicode. All I want is to use this text inside the app.

How can I do it by making sure that the fonts are displayed correctly?

Do I have to replace any font?

Please let me know any resources that might be of help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a text in Unicode you can simply put it to TextView which is placed inside ScrollView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22dp"/>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Put a text to TextView in a such way:

```
String yourText = ...;
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText(yourText);
```

Comment: So I don't have to ship any proprietary font, like suggested in some other threads? Great!

Comment: I do not check but you can try to use Typeface.createFromAsset method to load your font from a file and set it by TextView.setTypeface